# did anyone knows how to use qt creator debug child process?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, multiprocessing, qt-creator

I am not familiar with gdb debug.

But I need to debug with the children process.

I know there is a command set follow-fork-mode child. it will let gdb to response the child process. Could I change any setting in qt creator then I could use it to debug my code?

Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 6):

Go to `Tools > Options > Debugging > GDB Extended` and select `Debug all children`

Now when debugging you can switch between processes here:
[image]

Threads mean processes in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, It did could switch between different thread, but the Threads could not change to process, at least for my version of qt 2.5.2

Comment: @user2701639 could you change threads with the option I showed ? With one fork, there should be 2 threads.

Comment: I do not have the  GDB Extended at all. The only thing I have is GDB, and there are some box under it but none of them is "Debug all children". But I have Additional Startup Commands.  Could you tell me which version are you using?

Comment: @user2701639 Qt Creator is 3.1.1, so fairly new. You can add `set follow-fork-mode child` to your `Additional Startup Commands`. That way you will debug child process. (but no way of switching to parent during debug)

Comment: I tried to add the set follow-fork-mode child at the Additional Startup Commands. and then debug it. It shows warning: cannot insert breakpoint. Error accessing memory address 0xXXXXXXX. Input/Output error. Do you know what did it mean?

Comment: @user2701639 I never experienced it. From what I googled it may be a gdb or gcc bug.